# Is there any way to synchronize a list of servers in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have installed Minecraft on several different computers, and I want to synchronize the list of servers with all of my computers. Is there any way to do this (e. g., by linking the list of servers to my Minecraft account)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) account, any files stored there will be synced between computers that have your account linked.

What you then can do to sync the file is use a `symbolic link` between the minecraft file and your dropbox folder. A symbolic link is a special type of file, that contains a reference to another file or directory. The exact file you want to link to is `servers.dat`

For example, I synced my entire minecraft directory like so:

- I moved the `.minecraft` folder into my dropbox's Private folder
- Opened a `Command Prompt` window
- Navigated to where the .minecraft folder was using the `cd` command (For example, `cd "C:\Users\Robotnik\AppData\Roaming\"`
- Create the symbolic link using the `mklink` command (`mklink /D ".minecraft" "C:\Users\Robotnik\Dropbox\Private\My Games\.minecraft"`)

  - `/D` tells it to make a Directory symbolic link - if you only want to move one file leave this off- it will create a file link instead.

If you navigate to the link you just created using Explorer, it looks like a shortcut (it has the little arrow)

Obviously, if you're only moving `servers.dat`, you only need to move that one file.

I do this with all my save games that don't automatically sync with the cloud. You will need to create the symbolic link on each PC.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what a Symbolic Link is and does? It's also worth mentioning that you didn't MOVE the .minecraft folder, you must have COPIED it or else you wouldn't have been able to link them.

Comment: @Jason_c_o - *"A symbolic link  is a special type of file that contains a reference to another file or directory."* and yes, you need to actually *move* the `.minecraft` folder, i.e., there can't be a folder and a (directory) symbolic link with the same name in the same directory.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the specific file to sync for the server list is `servers.dat`.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - thanks, I've added that. Also added the definition of symbolic link