# If I buy Arma 2 through Steam will I be able to install it on multiple computers?

Tags: steam, arma-2

I'm about to buy Arma 2 through Steam, and I just want to make sure I'll be able to download it on both my dad's and my mom's computers to play. Can I or do I have to pick one?

Comment: How are you getting it? Through steam?

Comment: Yeah through steam

Comment: If it's from Steam then it'll be linked to your account so yes, you can play on multiple PCs (provided you don't try to play on both at the same time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can play your Steam games anywhere you log in. You'll have to download it all over again at each place, but once you do you can play it in both places.

I don't believe Arma 2 uses the Steam Cloud though, so your savegames will not follow you. However, if you are installing Arma 2 to play the popular DayZ mod, your savegame is stored on DayZ's own server and is connected to your Steam account, so that *would* travel with you just fine.

Comment: Can you use something like Dropbox for storing (and ideally for running) save games? i.e. set the save game location as your dropbox folder?

Comment: @JonW Why not? Does Dropbox limit the kind of files you can store? I'm using Skydrive, so I don't know about Dropbox.

Comment: @Nolonar I'm more asking as to whether ARMA2 / Dayz allows you to specify such a location for save files.

Comment: @JonW You can put anything in Dropbox, but no, Arma will not allow you to specify your savegame location. However! For DayZ you don't need to: your survivor is saved on DayZ's central server, and it's linked to your game's license key, so *that* will travel with you. To use Dropbox for non-DayZ Arma savegames, you'd have to work with symlinks, which is a whole other question.

Comment: @JonW - On the note of using Dropbox as a save-file syncing option: For games that have no way in-game of changing where saves are stored, you can move the folder containing the saves to Dropbox, and create a symbolic link (using `symlink` in command prompt) of the save game folder in it's original location. You'll need to do this on each PC. see the steps I wrote for syncing the `.minecraft` directory here: [Is there any way to synchronize a list of servers in Minecraft?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/97785/28182)

Answer (score 1):

If you buy a game through Steam you will normally be able to download it and play it on any number of machines. The game's [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARMA_2) implies there may have been some limits on the number of downloads, but that's not the case now. You will have to download the game onto each machine you want to play it on.

If you buy the DVD then you should be able to install it on multiple machines as games typically require the disk to be present even though they might not read any data off it during game play.